# java polymorphism and interface implementation

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm a 2nd Year Student and we're currently studying Java. I'm quite confused on how to do the two on the title especially here in the exercise that was provided for us. Hoping to get inputs and help. Thank you!

Question: Create an interface named **Comparison** whose method can be used to compare two
Time objects. The methods will include **isGreater, isLess, and isEqual**. Create another class that will implement these methods.

My code so far:

```
    import java.util.*;
    interface Comparison {
    boolean isGreater(Time x, Time y);
    boolean isLess(Time x,Time y);
    boolean isEqual(Time x, Time y);
}

public class Time implements Comparison {
    int am, pm;
    public boolean isGreater(Time x, Time y) {
        if (am > pm) {
            System.out.print("True");
        }
        else
            System.out.print("False");
    }
    public boolean isLess(Time x,Time y) {
        if (am < pm) {
            System.out.print("True");
        }
        else
            System.out.print("False");
    }
    public boolean isEqual(Time x, Time y) {
        
    }
    
}
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
        int x = new Time();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
        int y = new Time();
        
        }
    }
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you been given the `Time` class, or do you need to implement it yourself?

Comment: What compile time errors do you get, and do you understand what they mean?

Comment: We need to implement it ourselves and the errors I get are "class Main is public, should be declared in a file named Main.java" and "incompatible types: Time cannot be converted to int". I understand the latter, but its not the same for the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I correctly understand your query that you are trying to compare 2 different values of time if it is the only case then please refer the below code else please explain bit more about your requirement so i could correct the source code to help you.

as per your source code AM and PM are unrelated with time. we can pass time in 2 ways.

1. create own time class and used it.
2. use dateTime/Date/calendar classes which provide time values.

Step : 1 => create Main class.
Step : 2 => create an interface outside the class. make time data type to long.

```
interface Comparison {
    boolean isGreater(long xTime, long yTime);
    boolean isLess(long xTime, long yTime);
    boolean isEqual(long xTime, long yTime);
}
```

Step :3 => create a TimeManager[anyname] class to implement comparison interface. implement the interface methods.

```
class TimeManager implements Comparison {
    @Override
    public boolean isGreater(long xTime, long yTime) {
        return xTime > yTime ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLess(long xTime, long yTime) {
        return xTime < yTime ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEqual(long xTime, long yTime) {
        return xTime == yTime ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Step :4 => write calling statement into main method and pass time using date object from java.utils

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
            long x = new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
            long y = new Date().getTime();
    }
```

i hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This solved the problem on my end. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. Java compiler does not allow 2 `public` outer(top level) classes in the same java file
2. If a java file has a top level `public` class, then the file name should match the top level `public` class name
3. the comparison of `am` and `pm` seems unrelated to `Time` as per the sample code
4. in real code, `Time` references need to be checked for `null` values
5. A method with return type `boolean` should return a `boolean` value

### Sample code

```java
public boolean isGreater(Time x, Time y) {
  if (x == null && y == null) {
    return true; // you need to decide whether this is true or false
  } else if (x == null || y == null) {
    return false;
  }
  return x.getTime() > y.getTime(); // assumes getTime() returns a number
}
```

Comment: 1 sure ? can have as many public classes as you wanted (inner classes)

Comment: @TraianGEICU, Thank you for pointing out. I will update the answer for proper wording. I meant outer class (under the direct scope of file)

Comment: that's something else !